# filter dataframe on several columns using base or dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter the rows of a data frame based on columns in another datagram. Basically, I want to extract rows with the same IDs where the position is between start and end. There is the extra trick that the IDs are formatted differently.
finally, the data involved in the script is huge so to save memory or speed is nice to have.
would be grateful to get some tips.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                  pos = c(30, 40, 50, 35, 45, 55, 60, 63, 39))

df2 <- data.frame(idstr = c("id1", "id1", "id3", "id4", "id4"), 
                  start=c(30, 20, 30, 40, 20 ),
                  end = c(40, 30, 50, 60, 45))

df.base <- df1[ paste0("id", df1$id) == df2$idstr && 
                 df1$pos >= df2$start &&
                 df1$pos <= df2$end,]

df.dplyr <- df1 %>%
            left_join(df2, by  = c('id' == 'idstr') ) %>%
            filter(pos >= start & pos <= end) %>%
            select(id, pos)
```

edit:
expected output, the rows from df1 meeting the condition (their position is in a range of df2 with the same id), so if no mistake:
id, pos
1, 30
1, 40
3, 39

explanation: for example, df1[3,] id == 1 and pos == 50
looking at df2, there is no row where df2$id == "id1" and df2$start <= 50 and df2$end >= 50, so df1[3,] would be filtered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your 2 DF `df1` and `df2`, mutated column *idstr* from `df2` into a numeric by extracting the digits. Then with a `left_join`, `group_by` and `filter` I get the result.

```r
library(dplyr)


df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), pos = c(30, 40, 50, 35, 45, 55, 60, 63, 39))

df2 <- data.frame(idstr = c("id1", "id1", "id3", "id4", "id4"), 
                  start=c(30, 20, 30, 40, 20 ),
                  end = c(40, 30, 50, 60, 45))


df2 %>% 
  mutate(idstr = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(idstr, '[0-9]'))) %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c('idstr' = 'id')) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(pos >= start & pos <= end)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   idstr [2]
#>   idstr start   end   pos
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    30    40    30
#> 2     1    30    40    40
#> 3     1    20    30    30
#> 4     3    30    50    39
```

---

There is one `df1$id == 1` which fits into 2 start-end slots in `df2`. And therefore it has to be 3 positions with id =1.
If one of the limits is exlusive - like in the following code - it fits your wish.

```r
df2 %>% 
  mutate(idstr = as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(idstr, '[0-9]'))) %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c('idstr' = 'id')) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(pos > start & pos <= end)

#>   idstr start end pos
#> 1     1    30  40  40
#> 2     1    20  30  30
#> 3     3    30  50  39
```

Comment: it seems to work, i will adapt to my real data set, thank you! but one thing: it seems to me the group_by is meaningless? or am i missing something?

Comment: actually I am wrong, looking at row 3 of your output, this should not be there as it's the row1 of df1 being output twice. the goal is tow display all rows of df1 that match the condition, so if not mistake of my part, i would expect 3 rows as output for the dummy test i wrote. (original post edited to add the expected output. I guess i couldhide the problem but what if I had two rows with same id and pos in df1....

Comment: @Will key is the question, if the limits are meant inclusive. Please, have a look at the new edit.

Comment: Hi. if i follow, it's still not correct. the goal is to list the elements of df1 whose position is between a row of df2, so even if a row of df1 is matched by 2 rows of df2, in term of idstr and start and end (limit inclusive indeed), i would still want it to appear only once. I don't see a way to do that. the row number is lost so i can't filter on unique rows, and if I filter on unique (id, pos) then i would lose a row if two rows of df1 have same id and pos...

Answer (score 2):

We can use non-equi join in `data.table`.  Create the 'id' similar in both datasetss and then join `on` the 'id' columns and non-equi join with 'pos' and 'start', 'end' columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, id := paste0('id', id)]
df1[df2, on = .(id = idstr, pos >= start, pos <= end)]
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun for the suggestion. but i don't think it works: I get two rows with id 1 and pos 30 while i have only 1 such entry in df1. I haven't fully validated the result using MarBlo's suggestion yet but the behaviour looks more coherent at least.